# How does one debug a fastcgi application?

Tags: python, debugging, web-applications, fastcgi

How does one debug a FastCGI application?  I've got an app that's dying but I can't figure out why, even though it's likely throwing a stack trace on stderr.  Running it from the commandline results in an error saying:

```
RuntimeError: No FastCGI Environment: 88 - Socket operation on non-socket
```

How do I set up a 'FastCGI Environtment' for debugging purposes?  It's not my app - it's a 3rd party open source app - so I'd rather avoid adding in a bunch of logging to figure out what's going wrong.

If it matters, the app is Python, but FastCGI is FastCGI, right?  Is there a shim or something to let you invoke a fastcgi program from the commandline and hook it up to the terminal so you can see its stdout/stderr?

Comment: What framework?  What do you mean by "debugging"?

Comment: why don't you debug by logging?

Comment: ...because as I said, "It's not my app", so I'd like to be able to watch the fastcgi transactions going on and maybe debug those, or invoke it (validly) from the commandline and be able to see whatever it puts out on stdout/stderr.

Comment: logging is a pretty horrible way to debug stuff really.  A debugger attached to the process will provide a lot more information more quickly than adding numerous logs.

Answer (score 2):

It does matter that the application is Python; your question is really "how do I debug Python when I'm not starting the script myself".

You want to use a remote debugger.  The excellent WinPDB has [some documentation on embedded debugging](http://winpdb.org/docs/embedded-debugging/) which you should be able to use to attach to your FastCGI application and step through it.